# Increasing the height of table rows in R

Tags: html, css, r, dt

Please check the R code and snapshot below, I want to increase the height of the rows in the table.

```
library(DT)
datatable(head(iris), rownames = FALSE)
```

In order to achive this in css, you make use of:

```
#example tr td {
height: 894px;
}
```

[image: Description of Snapshot]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `formatStyle()` to change the row height:

```
library(DT)

datatable(head(iris), rownames = FALSE) %>%
  formatStyle(names(iris), # select all columns in table
              height = 894) # set height of rows
```

The output looks like this (first 2 rows only):

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, however, I figured it out myself, I used the font-size argument to reduce the row and text size.

Comment: I need your help with regarding dislaying data in a DT table in this post, please check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951307/selection-of-activity-trace-in-a-chart-and-display-in-a-data-table-in-r-shiny?noredirect=1#comment82886535_47951307